# I have created an angular directive for styling a table. But table loses the styles defined in the directive when pagination is clicked

Tags: angular, angular-ui, angular-directive, angular-components, angular2-directives

I have created the following custom directive in Angular:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[tableTheme]'
})
export class TableThemeDirective implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    tableElement: HTMLTableElement;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.tableElement = this.el.nativeElement;

        this.renderer.setStyle(this.tableElement, 'width', '100%');
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.tableElement, 'border-collapse', 'separate');
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.tableElement, 'border-spacing', '0 1em');
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.tableElement, 'color', 'white');

        const thElements: NodeListOf<HTMLTableCellElement> = this.tableElement.querySelectorAll('th');

        thElements.forEach((el) => {
            this.renderer.setStyle(el, 'height', '2em');
            this.renderer.setStyle(el, 'margin-bottom', '1em');
            this.renderer.setStyle(el, 'padding', '1em');
        });        
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        const tdElements: NodeListOf<HTMLTableCellElement> = this.tableElement.querySelectorAll('td');

        tdElements.forEach((el) => {
            this.renderer.setStyle(el, 'background-color', 'var(--primary-clr-light)');            
        });

        let tdFirstChildElements: HTMLTableCellElement[] = [];
        let tdLastChildElements: HTMLTableCellElement[] = [];

        tdElements.forEach((el) => {
            const parentNode: ParentNode = el.parentNode;
            
            if(el === parentNode.firstElementChild) {
                tdFirstChildElements.push(el);
            } else if(el === parentNode.lastElementChild) {
                tdLastChildElements.push(el);
            }
        });

        console.log(tdFirstChildElements);
        console.log(tdLastChildElements);
        

        tdFirstChildElements.forEach((el) => {
            this.renderer.setStyle(el, 'border-left-style', 'solid');
            this.renderer.setStyle(el, 'border-top-left-radius', '10px');
            this.renderer.setStyle(el, 'border-bottom-left-radius', '10px');
            this.renderer.setStyle(el, 'padding', '1em');
        });

        tdLastChildElements.forEach((el) => {
            this.renderer.setStyle(el, 'border-right-style', 'solid');
            this.renderer.setStyle(el, 'border-top-right-radius', '10px');
            this.renderer.setStyle(el, 'border-bottom-right-radius', '10px');
            this.renderer.setStyle(el, 'padding', '1em');
        });
    }
}
```

Then I use this directive to style a table:

```
<table class="user-table" tableTheme>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th> 
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Contact Number</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let user of displayingUsers">
            <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.role }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.contactNumber }}</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

As you can see the directive is attached to the table element.

Then I add some logic for pagination below the table:

```
  <div class="paginator">
    <button 
        class="btn btn-primary" 
        type="button" 
        *ngFor="let item of createRange(collectionLength); let i = index"
        (click)="onPaginationButtonClick(i + 1)">
        {{ i + 1 }}
    </button>
  </div>
```

Implementation of the pagination:

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  users: User[];
  displayingUsers: User[];
  currentPage: number = 1;
  perPage = 4;
  collectionLength: number;

  createRange(count: number): number[] {
    return new Array(count);
  }

  onPaginationButtonClick(clickedPage: number): void {
    this.displayingUsers = this.users.slice((clickedPage - 1) * this.perPage, (clickedPage - 1) * this.perPage + this.perPage);
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.users = USERS;
    this.onPaginationButtonClick(1);
    this.collectionLength = Math.ceil(this.users.length / this.perPage)
  }
}
```

Pagination completely works. But the table looses the style defined in the directive once the pagination buttons are clicked. (Following screenshots shows the problem.)

Before pagination buttons are clicked

[image]

After pagination buttons are clicked

[image]

As you can see the table loses the styles defined in the directive.

How to keep the styles defined in the directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **renderer.addClass** to add style to the element

```html
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tableElement = this.el.nativeElement;
    // add class(table-theme) to the component.css
    this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'table-theme');
  }
```

In HTML, wrap the table inside a div and apply your directive on the **div**

```
<div table-theme>
 <table>......</table>
<div>

Please find the working solution link below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9fqtkq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
```

Comment: Can you confirm why we are wrapping the table in a div and then applying the div directly to the table? Thank you.